# Remove duplicate elements from char array

Tags: java

This is a method where a `char[]` will be supplied as an input and it should return an array, but without the duplicate elements. How can this be optimized?

```
private static char[] getMYCharArray(char[] array) {
        String myArray = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(myArray.indexOf(array[i]) == -1) // check if a char already exist, if not exist then return -1
                myArray = myArray+array[i];      // add new char
        }
        return myArray.toCharArray();
    }
```

Comment: myArray.indexOf is O(n).   But on a short list not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use a `Set`. Just add the elements from the array and then get the unique elements from the `Set`. This algorithm will be `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)` because each element is accessed only once.

Note that you can use `Arrays.asList()` to simplify the coding, too.

Comment: I just tried using a `LinkedHashSet<Character>` instead of a `HashSet<Character>` combined with a `char[]`, and they both seem to be about equally fast. Sometimes, one is a bit faster, sometimes the other.

Comment: @Stingy That sounds like a reasonable result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly convoluted algorithm that yields the same result as yours but is faster. It takes advantage of Java's native support for arrays instead of using an internal `String`:

```java
private static char[] getYOURCharArray(char[] array) {
    char[] distinctChars = new char[0];
    char[] distinctCharsInOriginalOrder = new char[array.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int binarySearchResult = Arrays.binarySearch(distinctChars, array[i]);

        if (binarySearchResult < 0) {
            char[] updatedDistinctChars = new char[distinctChars.length + 1];
            int insertionPointForNewChar = -(binarySearchResult + 1);

            System.arraycopy(distinctChars, 0, updatedDistinctChars, 0, insertionPointForNewChar);
            updatedDistinctChars[insertionPointForNewChar] = array[i];
            System.arraycopy(distinctChars, insertionPointForNewChar, updatedDistinctChars, insertionPointForNewChar + 1, distinctChars.length - insertionPointForNewChar);

            distinctChars = updatedDistinctChars;
            distinctCharsInOriginalOrder[distinctChars.length - 1] = array[i];
        }
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(distinctCharsInOriginalOrder, distinctChars.length);
}
```

Using `Arrays.binarySearch(char[], char)` to look for a `char` in a `char[]` seems to be faster than searching for a `char` in a `String` using `String.indexOf(int)`. On the other hand, `Arrays.binarySearch(char[], char)` requires the `char[]` to be sorted, which is why we need a second `char[]` that stores all distinct characters in the order they were first encountered in the original `char[]`, assuming the returned `char[]` must fulfill this requirement (if it doesn't, then the array `distinctCharsInOriginalOrder` is actually not needed and you can return `distinctChars` directly at the end of this method, which might speed up the process a little bit). To ensure that `distinctChars` stays sorted, it is important to insert new `char`s at the correct position when updating `distinctChars`, which is why two calls to `System.arraycopy` are needed.

I did some simulations with random `char` arrays, each containing 100000 random characters. Here are the results of a set of 10 simulations:

```
With String: 9.183 seconds
With char arrays: 2.404 seconds

With String: 4.159 seconds
With char arrays: 2.075 seconds

With String: 4.721 seconds
With char arrays: 2.116 seconds

With String: 4.758 seconds
With char arrays: 2.056 seconds

With String: 4.517 seconds
With char arrays: 2.056 seconds

With String: 4.707 seconds
With char arrays: 2.038 seconds

With String: 4.803 seconds
With char arrays: 2.049 seconds

With String: 4.706 seconds
With char arrays: 2.024 seconds

With String: 4.683 seconds
With char arrays: 2.045 seconds

With String: 4.549 seconds
With char arrays: 2.052 seconds
```

I have no idea why the first simulation with the `String` algorithm takes twice as long as all the others. It was like that every time I ran the program, even when I switched the order of the two tests (meaning the first `String` algorithm still took twice as long as the others, even when the `char[]` algorithm was tested first). Maybe I did something wrong, or the JVM does something mysterious here.

Apparently, the larger the original `char` array, the greater the difference between the performance of the two algorithms. Here are the results of 10 simulations with 500000 random characters:

```
With String: 20.44 seconds
With char arrays: 4.474 seconds

With String: 21.344 seconds
With char arrays: 3.489 seconds

With String: 22.064 seconds
With char arrays: 3.315 seconds

With String: 22.155 seconds
With char arrays: 3.351 seconds

With String: 22.325 seconds
With char arrays: 3.386 seconds

With String: 22.149 seconds
With char arrays: 3.335 seconds

With String: 22.175 seconds
With char arrays: 3.352 seconds

With String: 22.16 seconds
With char arrays: 3.343 seconds

With String: 22.502 seconds
With char arrays: 3.362 seconds

With String: 22.122 seconds
With char arrays: 3.351 seconds
```

Comment: It turns out that, if the order of `char`s in the returned `char[]` does not matter, using a `HashSet<Character>` is much,  _much_ faster than this approach.

Comment: Actually, even if the order does matter, using a `HashSet<Character>` to store all distinct characters, and a `char[]` to store these characters in their original order, is way faster than using two `char[]`s. So the simplest approach wins, after all …

Comment: Most likely, the original `String` solution is slower because it creates a new `String` each time it adds a character. This will copy the entire previous `String` each time a character is appended.

Comment: @Code-Guru Well, the `char` array version also creates a new array every time a new character is encountered, copying the characters of the old array, so I don't think Object creation itself is what makes the `char[]` version faster than the `String` version. I rather suspect it's because `System.arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int)` is a native method, but I'm no expert, so it's just an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

(sorry for the brevity and typos, writing on a phone)

Assuming that you are only using ASCII characters you can simply keep a boolean array and keep track of characters seen like so:

```
char noDupes(char[] input) {
    boolean[] seen = new boolean [256];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (input.length);
    for ( char c : input){
        if(!seen[c]){
            sb.append(c);
            seen[c]=true;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

If input isn't limited to ASCII, simply use a HashSet instead of the boolean array but the array is faster.

Comment: If we're assuming ASCII input, then 128 bools are sufficient.  256 are required for Latin-1 characters (and, obviously, 65536 for all the UTF-16 code-points a Java `char` can actually hold).

Comment: @TobySpeight Extended ASCII still contains code points in the upper 128. I should have specified better.

Comment: Well, that's not ASCII (arguably, you could call Unicode and ISO 10646 - up to the astral planes - "extended ASCII", given the superset relationship, but that's not very helpful).  I've actually seen a hybrid approach work well - a bool array for small values (up to 128 or 256, perhaps), and a hash table for larger values.  That's a good technique for Latin-script languages, where most characters take the fast path.